# Better understanding "not an answer" flags

Tags: support, flagging, not-an-answer

I have flagged this post for not being an answer: [Checking NVRAM on BootUp](https://superuser.com/questions/594147/checking-nvram-on-bootup/792169#792169)

The flag was declined, as "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". I am new to SU and I'm still finding the line on what's an answer or not :-)

Now, this is not the first flag I make where this happens (it's the second). But this time, I can't see why this is an answer. This is a user saying "it happened to me too", and describing his situation. It *is* related to the question, unlike other situations I've seen.

But is this considered an answer just because it's related to the question, or am I missing something in my assessment?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8311/another-possibly-wrong-review-audit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this flag was declined because the moderator saw the following text in the user's answer...

> On going into BIOS and checking the boot sequence I found that the Kindle had become the 1st boot device, and of course the PC couldn't boot from a Kindle! Changed the boot order back to the main hard drive and it booted-up as normal, with the Kindle still connected.

... and thought that, **because the user provides a solution that worked for them** (even if this is not the best / most accurate solution, and even if it doesn't work for the OP), this is *not* "Not An Answer".

I would tend to agree.

However, if you have specific experience in this area and you believe that the solution the user proposed is unlikely to help the OP in any way, you can register your assessment by simply downvoting the post and leaving a comment describing what is incorrect about the answer, or how it would fail to help the OP.

Based on my experience in this area, I think [this](https://superuser.com/a/594152/144607) answer is more likely to be correct, as the symptom observed by the OP was a clock reset, not a failure to boot. The guy who added the answer you linked to seems to have a separate issue about his computer trying to boot from an attached mobile device.

But since an *answer was provided* (even if it misses the mark), the most we can do is downvote. If it gets many downvotes, it'll likely be deleted.

(OP = Original Poster; the person who asked the question)

Comment: This is the reason

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought it wasn't an answer precisely because the OP's problem was the CMOS being erased, not being unable to boot - the answer didn't address the question. I thought this should, at most, be considered a comment, not an answer. I also agree that the answer you linked to seems to be the correct one.